# Reading static files in ASP.NET Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.0, blazor-client-side

I have a client side Blazor Application. I want to have an `appsetting.json` file for my client-side configuration like we have an `environment.ts` in 
Angular.

For that, I am keeping a `ConfigFiles` folder under `wwwroot` and a JSON file inside of it. I am trying to read this file as below.

First get the path:

```cs
public static class ConfigFiles
{
    public static string GetPath(string fileName)
    {
        return Path.Combine("ConfigFiles", fileName);
    }
}
```

Than read it:

```cs
public string GetBaseUrl()
{
    string T = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        T = File.ReadAllText(ConfigFiles.GetPath("appsettings.json"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        T = ex.Message;
    }
    return T;
}
```

But I always get the error:

> Could not find a part of the path "/ConfigFiles/appsettings.json".

Inside the `GetPath()` method, I also tried:

```cs
return Path.Combine("wwwroot/ConfigFiles", fileName);
```

But I still get the same error:

> Could not find a part of the path "wwwroot/ConfigFiles/appsettings.json".

Since there is no concept of `IHostingEnvironment`in client-side Blazor, what is the correct way to read a static JSON file here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I have a client side Blazor Application

OK, That means that `File.ReadAllText(...)` and `Path.Combine(...)` are not going to work at all. 
Client-side means that you could be running on Android or Mac-OS or whatever.

The Blazor team provides you with a complete sample of how to read a file, in the form of the FetchData sample page.

```
forecasts = await Http.GetJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("sample-data/weather.json");
```

this gets you the contents of a file in `wwwroot/sample-data`
You can use `Http.GetStringAsync(...)` if you want AllText

If you want to have per-user settings then look into the Blazored.LocalStorage package.

Comment: Ok , so most of the thing has to be done by api call now , sweet

Comment: Thank you so much for that GetStringAsync!!

Comment: How about a link to the sample from the Blazor Team?

Comment: it looks like this one here: https://github.com/torhovland/blazor-realworld-example-app/blob/master/src/BlazorRealworld/Pages/FetchData.cshtml
But for me (net5.0) `GetJsonAsync` is unknown, now it's `GetFromJsonAsync`. Only for WebAsembly!

Comment: GetFromJsonAsync is an extension method, you can add it to Serverside as well. It's a package.

Comment: I dont want to do a web request, just read a file. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, don't write a Web app.